# window.confirm() in java servlet

Tags: javascript, java, servlets

In web app I want to get an answer to questions in servlet;

```
PrintWriter out1 = response.getWriter();  
            response.setContentType("text/html");  
            out1.println("<script type=\"text/javascript\">");  
            out1.println("confirm('question?');");  
            out1.println("</script>");
```

this code give me a confirm dialog , but i dont know how to get the answer of it in servlet

Is there is a possible way?

Comment: capture the result in a variable and send it through url or hidden form field when requesting the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The servlet is server side code. is The confirm is client side, in the browser. It returns true or false depending on what button the user clicks. You need to capture that result in javascript in the browser and send it to the server for the servlet to see.

If you have a series of questions then you might be best to use a form, rather than the confirm dialog. Multiple confirm dialogs gives a really bad user experience. In your servlet response you would create a html form, and then inside the form create an input for each question. The form also provides a ready made way to submit the results back to your servlet.

Comment: this answer better suits as a comment!

Comment: I have to ask the user more than one question, the content of each question i can only know in servlet.
So i have to get more than one answer and i dont know the number of questions each time.
so I ask if there's a way to make it easy. and hidden fields in server side is not right answer